# Error on Main Camera in Unity: "The renderer used by this camera doesn't support camera stacking. Only Base camera will render."

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just updated my unity version from 2018 to 2019. Also, I've got a new render pipeline for the 2D lights feature, and there is this weird white flickering when my character moves, and even sometimes without movement. I think the Main Camera warning shown in the title is the cause, but I could be wrong. Does anyone have a fix?

Comment: Are there, maybe by accident, multiple active cameras in the scene? (You can search by type in the advanced hierarchy search options.)

Comment: Looks like you configured camera stacking, which came along with URP 7.2.0, however you cannot do that by accident.  If you don't want camera stacking then clear its configuration in the camera(s).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the problem you referenced in your description, but as for the error in your title I had a similar problem and it was because I had two cameras in the scene, one overlay and one base, the overlay was for my UI and I was using Universal Render Pipeline with 2D which is not yet supported.  So I cannot stack multiple cameras, when I do it will only load the base camera.

https://forum.unity.com/threads/does-urp-support-ui-canvas-overlay.768077/

Answer (score 0):

you may try to select main camera than at inspector section open "rendering" and mark the "renderer" as "UniversalRendererPipelineAsset".

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using 'deferred' rendering, and camera stacking is only supported on forward rendering.

Either select forward rendering on your Universal pipeline asset, or create a new render pipeline asset with forward rendering and assign it to the camera.

If you are unsure which one to choose, read: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RenderingPaths.html